# Keras deep clustering undefined errors in clustering custom layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning, cluster-analysis

i was following this guide to implement a clustering into a deep model
https://ai-mrkogao.github.io/reinforcement%20learning/clusteringkeras/ but i got two errors :

1. The first one, on this line

   clustering_layer = ClusteringLayer(n_clusters, name='clustering')(encoder.output)

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in build
TypeError: add_weight() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

So i located

```
self.clusters = self.add_weight((self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='clusters')
```

from the class ClusteringLayer and i removed name='clusters' as follow

```
self.clusters = self.add_weight((self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

But now it keeps giving me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
    self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in build
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 282, in add_weight
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 620, in variable
    value, dtype=dtype, name=name, constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 782, in variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 460, in __init__
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 582, in _init_from_args
    if init_from_fn else [initial_value]) as name:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6513, in __enter__
    return self._name_scope.__enter__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4306, in name_scope
    if not _VALID_SCOPE_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here is the complete and reproducible code

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer, InputSpec
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import callbacks
from keras.initializers import VarianceScaling
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


def autoencoder(dims, act='relu', init='glorot_uniform'):
    n_stacks = len(dims) - 1
    input_img = Input(shape=(dims[0],), name='input')
    x = input_img
    for i in range(n_stacks-1):
        x = Dense(dims[i + 1], activation=act, kernel_initializer=init, name='encoder_%d' % i)(x)
    encoded = Dense(dims[-1], kernel_initializer=init, name='encoder_%d' % (n_stacks - 1))(x)  # hidden layer, features are extracted from here
    x = encoded
    for i in range(n_stacks-1, 0, -1):
        x = Dense(dims[i], activation=act, kernel_initializer=init, name='decoder_%d' % i)(x)
    x = Dense(dims[0], kernel_initializer=init, name='decoder_0')(x)
    decoded = x
    return Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=decoded, name='AE'), Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=encoded, name='encoder')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x = np.concatenate((x_train, x_test))
y = np.concatenate((y_train, y_test))
x = x.reshape((x.shape[0], -1))
x = np.divide(x, 255.)

x_train.shape
x.shape
n_clusters = len(np.unique(y))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=20, n_jobs=4)
y_pred_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(x)
y_pred_kmeans[:10]
dims = [x.shape[-1], 500, 500, 2000, 10]
init = VarianceScaling(scale=1. / 3., mode='fan_in',distribution='uniform')
pretrain_optimizer = SGD(lr=1, momentum=0.9)
autoencoder, encoder = autoencoder(dims, init=init)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=pretrain_optimizer, loss='mse')
autoencoder.fit(x, x, batch_size=250, epochs=2) #, callbacks=cb)
autoencoder.save_weights( 'ae_weights.h5')

class ClusteringLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_clusters, weights=None, alpha=1.0, **kwargs):
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
        super(ClusteringLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.initial_weights = weights
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=2)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 2
        input_dim = input_shape[1]
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(dtype=K.floatx(), shape=(None, input_dim))
        self.clusters = self.add_weight((self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform')
        if self.initial_weights is not None:
            self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
            del self.initial_weights
        self.built = True
    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):    
        q = 1.0 / (1.0 + (K.sum(K.square(K.expand_dims(inputs, axis=1) - self.clusters), axis=2) / self.alpha))
        q **= (self.alpha + 1.0) / 2.0
        q = K.transpose(K.transpose(q) / K.sum(q, axis=1)) # Make sure each sample's 10 values add up to 1.
        return q
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
        return input_shape[0], self.n_clusters
    def get_config(self):
        config = {'n_clusters': self.n_clusters}
        base_config = super(ClusteringLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
clustering_layer = ClusteringLayer(n_clusters, name='clustering')(encoder.output)
model = Model(inputs=encoder.input, outputs=clustering_layer)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(0.01, 0.9), loss='kld')
model.get_layer(name='clustering').set_weights([kmeans.cluster_centers_])
encoder.output
clustering_layer
 784 image input -> 10 classification
```

The result of

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

is

```
2.2.4-tf
```

You can even download the docker with keras installation at repbioinfo/autoencoderforclustering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the error, just correct these line

```
self.clusters = self.add_weight(shape = (self.n_clusters, input_dim),
initializer='glorot_uniform', name='clusters')
```

instead of

```
 self.clusters = self.add_weight((self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform')
```